# extracting text from HTML

Tags: bash, html, filter, table

I have [this page](http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=8.8.8.8). I want to extract text from html page, particularly table heading (`th`) and table data (`td`). For example:

**Country: United States (US)**,**State: California** where `th` = Country and `td` = United States (US).

This is the closest I could get, using `xidel`:

```
xidel -A  "Mozilla/5.0" http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php ip=8.8.8.8 -e 'th[1] td[1]'
```

How do I extract all `th` and `td` table entries in the html page?

Comment: I din't think anyone will do this work for you (for free). I assume you read the manual to xidel. Did you try the Xidel Template tester (http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi)? I'm sure this will get you to a solution quickly. And maybe you're lucky and someone did just that and can share their code here.

Comment: @vic your link was helpful. I have reformed my code as follow--           xidel --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0" http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=8.8.8.8 -e "<table> 
<tbody>
<template:loop>
<tr> 
<th> {$field1} </th> 
<td> {$field2} </td> 
</tr>
</template:loop>
</tbody>
</table>
"
 I don't get any output. Instead I get a message saying 'current variable state'.Everything looks fine when i checked here http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Great, glad to hear you got it right now :)

Comment: @vic I did not. Read the above comment. I have discussed my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I was on mobile and the last two lines were cut.. I can't help you, I don't use xidel. But if your code worked in the (official) template checker, you obviously can't be far from the solution.

Comment: I know man. I am close enough. Anyways thanks for sharing that link. It was helpful.